# Angular - No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following error

Tags: angular

Below is the code for `token.get()` in my Angular-12 application:

```
get(){
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
```

Then I have the below mentioned code in my Service:

```
//GET Method
public getAllTerms(): Observable<any> {
   const headers = {     //Token for API Authorization
    'Authorization' : this.token.get(),
    'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }
  return this.http.get(`${this.api.baseURL}core/students`, headers);
}
```

My POST gave me a response without any. But in Angular, I got this error:

```js
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Type '{ Authorization: string | null; '
X - Requested - With ': string; }'
has no properties in common with type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } | undefined; context?: HttpContext | undefined; observe?: "body" | undefined; params?: HttpParams | { ...; } | undefined; reportProgress?: boolean | undefined; responseType?: "json" | undefined; withCredentials?: boolean | undefined; }'.ts(2769)
http.d.ts(1149, 5): The last overload is declared here.
const headers: {
    Authorization: string | null;
    'X-Requested-With': string;
```

headers is highlighted

If I change it to:

```
 public getAllTerms(): Observable<any> {
   const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
   return this.http.get(`${this.api.baseURL}core/students`, { headers, responseType: 'json' });
 }
```

The error change to:

> 401 (Unauthorized)

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
get(){
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
```

Could return `null` if the token is not present, hence its definition is implicitly the following :
`get(): string | null`.

Since Angular use typescript, it is strictly typed, so `string | null` != `string`.

I guess this will solve your problem :

```
get(): string {
  return localStorage.getItem('token') ?? 'unauthenticated'; 
  // ?? operator is explained here https://indepth.dev/posts/1300/double-question-marks-typescript-3-7-nullish-coalescing
}
```